# Are all mammals capable of sneezing?

Tags: evolution, zoology, physiology

I only know dogs and humans sneeze... so do other mammals sneeze as well? Is it possibly an evolutionarily-determined immunological trigger?

Comment: Are you really asking about all animals (including  jellyfish for example)  or rather about mammals, as your examples imply?

Comment: Dogs and cats sneeze. My dog sneezes of excitement every morning when we're going out. A sponge - having no nose - obviously does not sneeze.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Yes, I’m asking about all animals. I know about humans and dogs (examples of mammals) hence why I asked if “other animals sneeze as well”.

Comment: @P.SN Note that to a biologist, "animals" is quite a broad taxonomic grouping, and as Marzipanherz and Remi.b point out includes plenty of organisms that have no lungs or nose or respiratory system at all.

Comment: @Marzipanherz give the OP a break. Sponges sneeze. It's a reasonable question. This is why I like beginner questions. They aren't closed off to ideas that seem implausible to experts.

Comment: @DanHall Unclear questions are unclear. They are not open-minded because they are unclear. It is at the core of the SE format to require the question to be clearly defined by the OP. We don't want a discussion in a post, we want a clear question and a clear answer.

Comment: @Remi.b The question wasn't unclear. It was very clear. Are all animals capable of sneezing? That's a clear, interesting, answerable question. No, not all animals sneeze. Yes, some animals you might think of as not being able to sneeze can.

Comment: @Remi.b  A dog and a human both happen to be mammals, but they are also both animals. The reason the original question was interpreted as unclear was that the "savy" readers didn't think non-mammals could sneeze.

Comment: @DanHall I never doubted the question was reasonable- On the contrary, I find it very interesting. I just wanted to make sure that there is no misunderstanding due to the potential different use of the term _animal_ by a beginner and an expert. I used to believe that this what comments are meant for.

Comment: Just curious.  Why/how did the title of the question change?  I thought the OP said all animals in the comments above.  Did the OP change their mind?

Comment: @wanderweeer Yes OP improved the post based on the comments and modified "animal" to "mammal".

Comment: @DanHall To double on what marzipanherz said, I never meant that the question was fundamentally crap. I meant that some elements of this question were unclear. OP still has not fully addressed them IMO but I removed my vote close when OP edited its post. Anyway... Let's not fight any further on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [national geographic post](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/06/150627-animals-science-elephants-anatomy-sneezing/) discusses many mammals that sneeze. It doesn't come right out and say *all*, but suggests most mammals have a cough and sneeze reflex:

> Mammal coughs and sneezes come from throat and nasal passages, respectively, says Bill Milsom, a comparative physiologist at the University of British Columbia.
>
> Mammals, he says, are the only animals that process food in the mouth by chewing. In other types of animals, like reptiles, "food is swallowed whole or by chewing, and breathing is suspended during the event."

The same expert discusses non-mammals that sneeze, marine iguanas and fish.

You don't even need nerves or muscles to sneeze, per this [Cell Press article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18211843)

> Sponges 'sneeze' without the benefit of nerves or muscles